# extract a float from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I know that we can extract an integer value from a string using

```
var x = "> 1";
x = parseInt(x.match(/\d+/)[0], 10));
```

How do I get a float value from a string

example: `var x = "> 1.1"`

I know we can just use `x.substring(2);`

But for a more generic solution? since the above will not give the accurate result for

```
var x = "1.1"
```

So what is the best way to extract the float value `1.1` from

```
var x = "> 1.1"
```

Comment: How about `/\d+\.?\d*/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` and a regular expression that matches a number with optional decimals and minus sign.

```
var f = parseFloat(x.match(/-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following one to extract only numbers like floating or integer as an array as many as you want using the match function.

```
str = 'On schedule: 3243.8 miles away (4491 minutes)';
values = str.match(/[0-9.]+/g); //=> ["3243.8", "4491"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = parseFloat(x.match(/[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/));
```

Comment: Please explain your solution so that future visitors to this question will understand how it solves the problem at hand.

Comment: The argument matches a number with an optional + or - sign followed by at least one digit followed by an optional decimal point with at least one digit following the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It won't skip over the `>` at the beginning.